# Resource Allocation Problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, integer-programming, dynamic-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Let $I, J, n \in \mathbb N$. Furthermore, let $\mathbf M \in \mathbb N^{I \times J}$.  Finally, for $i \in \{1, \dots, I\}$ and $j \in \{1, \dots, J\}$, let $M(i,j)$ denote the element in the $i$th row and $j$th column of $\mathbf M$.  I'd like to solve the following optimization problem:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\max_{\mathbf x \in \mathbb N^I} && \sum_{i=1}^I\sum_{j = 1}^J\min\{M(i,j), x_i\} \\
&\text{ s.t.} && \sum_{i=1}^I x_i = n.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I suspect that the problem can be solved by a "greedy" algorithm with the following form:

1. Set $\mathbf x \equiv \mathbf 0$.
2. Pick any $\mathbf k \in \arg \max \sum_{i=1}^I\sum_{j = 1}^J\min\{M(i,j), x_i + \delta_k\}$. In words, find a component of $\mathbf x$ which maximally increases the objective value when incremented by one -- allowing for the possibility that there may be multiple components which give maximal increase.
3. Set $\mathbf x \equiv \mathbf x + \mathbf e_k$, where $\mathbf e_k$ is the $k$th coordinate vector.
4. If $\sum_{i=1}^I x_i = n$, stop; otherwise, return to step 2.

However, I am not sure how to prove that this greedy algorithm leads to an optimal solution.

Can you help me by either providing a proof or counter-example?